# WFS Filtered : The filters that worked for me in 1.8 - gives no results in 2.0

Tags: qgis, wfs, qgis-2, filter, getfeature

Using Quantum GIS 1.8.0 and 2.0.1 desktop on windows XP 32bit

Server: http://vmgeoserver.vd.dk/geoserver/VD/ows?

Setting filter for VD:vma_admdata:

```
"BESTYRER"  = '230' AND  "KODE_ADMIN_VINTERVEJSERVI"  = '230_V1' AND  "KODE_ADMIN_VEDLIGEHOLD_NI" = '230_N'
```

In 1.8 this returns the results I'm looking for.
Metadata for the resulting layer states *Source for this layer:*

```
http://vmgeoserver.vd.dk/geoserver/VD/ows?version=1.1.0&SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=VD:vma_admdata&SRSNAME=EPSG:25832&FILTER= BESTYRER 230 KODE_ADMIN_VINTERVEJSERVI 230_V1 KODE_ADMIN_VEDLIGEHOLD_NI 230_N
```

Doing the same in Quantum GIS 2.0.1 gives no error messages but the resulting layer is empty. Checking metadata the *Source for this layer* is:

```
http://vmgeoserver.vd.dk/geoserver/VD/ows?version=1.1.0&SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=VD:vma_admdata&SRSNAME=EPSG:25832&FILTER= BESTYRER 230 KODE_ADMIN_VINTERVEJSERVI 230_V1 KODE_ADMIN_VEDLIGEHOLD_NI 230_N
```

i.e.. identical.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at this bugreport: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/8584

Comment: Thanks Juergen. 
The namespace `xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"`
was missing from my qgis project file and adding it manually (notepad) gets it working